# Can't access specific files

Tags: linux, files, rhel

I have 5 text files in a directory. They all have the same permissions (`-rw-r--r--`) and the same owner (`tom`). However, two of the files cannot be accessed by tom. For example, `cat Fourier.f` results in "Operation not permitted". Vi fails too. Access to the other three files is as expected.

Below is the result of `ls -ail`:

```
total 20
134227359 drwxr-xr-x.  2 tom tom  85 Nov 14 11:27 .
     6867 drwxr-xr-x. 12 tom tom 148 Oct  3 21:53 ..
134227364 -rw-r--r--.  1 tom tom 811 Sep 21 16:55 blocks.f
134227363 -rw-r--r--.  1 tom tom 413 Sep 21 16:55 formats.f
134227360 -rw-r--r--.  1 tom tom 113 Sep 21 16:55 Fourier.f
134227362 -rw-r--r--.  1 tom tom 309 Sep 21 16:55 index.f
134227361 -rw-r--r--.  1 tom tom 492 Sep 21 16:55 OptF.f
```

`Fourier.f` and `OptF.f` are the affected files. I noticed they are both capitalized, if that matters, for some crazy reason.

The files can be accessed using `sudo`.

- The OS is a new install of RHEL 8.7 workstation.
- LUKS encryption is being used on the filesystem.
- The filesystem is xfs.
- I implemented a security policy using oscap.

The files are created by downloading a zip file and running `unzip`.

I've tried downloading it a few times to different locations with the same result.

I am doing the same on an Ubuntu machine, resulting in files that are accessible as expected.

Update:

Playing around, I noticed the following.

Consider a file with hex values as below

```
00000000: 2020 2020 2020 6d6f 6475 6c65 2046 6f75        module Fou
00000010: 2020 7361 7665 0a20 2020 2020 2065 6e64    save.      end
00000020: 0a                                       .
```

If I run `xxd -r <file> out.f`, `out.f` cannot be accessed, like above.

If I change the `F` (46 hex) to `f` (66 hex) and run `xxd` in the same way, the output can be accessed. So the content of the file seems to be used to determine access. Weird.

I came across this because I ran `xxd Fourier.f > Fhex` to look at the hex to see if anything was weird, then started taking stuff out to see the effect.

Comment: The trailing '`.`' on the permissions suggest there are ACLs on these files.  Does `getfacl -a Fourier.f OptF.f` show anything consistent with the user `tom` lacking permissions to read them?

Comment: @SottoVoce trailing `+`  indicates ACLs, but trailing `.` indicates a file with an SELinux security context. Tom, you should run `ls -Z` on the directory to print the security context of each file.

Comment: ls -lZ produces the same results for all files other than the file size.

Comment: getfacl -a produces the same results for all 5 files other than the file name

Comment: What installed these files?

Comment: The files came from a zip file via unzip. They do not appear to be corrupt as they function normally on another computer.

Comment: Some form of on-access antivirus enabled?

Comment: I didn't install any antivirus and RHEL apparently doesn't provide it.

Answer (score 1):

The culprit was `fapolicyd`. I ran `systemctl stop fapolicyd` and was then able to access the files as expected. So the next step is to figure out how to configure the policies so this doesn't happen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).